# Consulta com critérios combinados

Tags: mysql, query

Estou tentando atribuir mais de um critério de pesquisa no banco de dados e não consigo encontrar nada que possa me ajudar. Vou explicar melhor:

Tenho um banco de dados com um campo "cidade", aonde eu quero que sejam retornados os daos atribuídos àquela cidade. Porém, eu desejo que outra cidade próxima seja incluída também, mas não gostaria de fazer isso com uma tabela auxiliar.

Já vi isso sendo usado com vírgulas nos formulários, mas não tenho ideia de como fazer isso na query.

```
$acha = mysqli_query("
SELECT *
FROM pe_basedecisao 
WHERE cidade = 351015, 351013");
```

Comment: Você pode usar um `OR` na condição pelo que entendi `SELECT * FROM pe_basedecisao WHERE cidade = 351015 OR cidade = 351013`

Comment: SELECT * FROM pe_basedecisao WHERE cidade IN ("351015", "351013");

Comment: Obrigado galera!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Você pode fazer isso com IN no mysql:

***Query usando 'IN'***

```
SELECT * FROM pe_basedecisao WHERE cidade IN ("351015", "351013");
```

***Tradução dessa query sem 'IN'***

```
SELECT * FROM pe_basedecisao WHERE cidade = "351015" OR cidade = "351013";
```

Referência : [MySQL IN](https://www.techonthenet.com/mysql/in.php)